# What is the boundary for p such that $\sum \frac {(-1)^n} {(\sqrt {n}+(-1)^n)^p}$ is absolute convergent, conditional convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am working on the problem, I tried to simplify it

$\frac {(-1)^n} {(\sqrt {n}+(-1)^n)^p}$

=$(\frac 1 {\sqrt n+1})^p$ when p is even and $-(\frac 1 {\sqrt n-1})^p$ when p is odd

=$\frac 1 2[(\frac 1 {\sqrt n+1})^p-(\frac 1 {\sqrt n-1})^p]+\frac 1 2 (-1)^n [(\frac 1 {\sqrt n+1})^p+(\frac 1 {\sqrt n-1})^p]$

but i failed to analyze the first part of the equation when p<2.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to tackle the problem. Define $s_k:=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^i$ and $a_n:=\frac{(-1)^n}{(\sqrt n+(-1)^n)^p}$. Since $s_k=0$ if $k$ is odd, the problem reduces after a summation by part, to the convergence of the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}((2k)^{1/2}+1)^{-p}-((2k+1)^{1/2}-1)^{-p}.$$
Since the series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}((2k)^{1/2}+1)^{-p}-((2k+1)^{1/2}+1)^{-p}$ is convergent for $p>0$ (alternated series), we are reduces to deal with the convergence of the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}((2k+1)^{1/2}+1)^{-p}-((2k+1)^{1/2}-1)^{-p}.$$
This can be done factoring the term $(2k+1)^{1/2}$ and using the Taylor expansion of $(1+t)^{-p}$ at $0$.